# Problem with sending .mkv files with socket in java

Tags: java, serversocket

I am trying to send a .mkv file with a Java server socket. The file is beeing transmitted normally but when I try to open it with VLC Media Player it only shows the first second of the film and then the pircture freezes.

Server:

```
public class Server {

public void run_server(){
    try {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client at port " + server.getLocalPort() + "\n");

        while (true) {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            executorService.execute(new Handler(client));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server s = new Server();
    s.run_server();
}

public class Handler implements Runnable {

private Socket client;

public Handler(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("client connected: " + client.getInetAddress());
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\Filme\\Asterix und das Geheimnis des Zaubertranks (2018).mkv");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[522231808];
        fin.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The client:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Client()).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test\\test.mkv");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[522231808];
        in.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
        fout.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the return value from in.read(), it tells you how many bytes were actually read. You will probably find it is less than you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try a smaller buffer:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
    for (int n = in.read(buffer); n > 0; n = in.read(buffer)) {
        fout.write(buffer,0,n);
    }
```

Comment: ... and yes: get the return value of `in.read(buffer)`.

Comment: But the .mkv file is around half an gigabyte big so if i take a smaller buffer the file will not be fully sent. 

And if I do this:


``byte[] buffer = new byte[in.read()];

            in.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);

            fout.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);``
The size of the new file is 0 bytes